# Associate ec2 to godaddy on tomcat using 8080 port

Tags: html, web, amazon-ec2, hosting, web-hosting

I created an ec2 instance and installed apache tomcat on that instance.
I have my java and html code on that apache 8080 server. I want to host the html folder of the code to godaddy. The address for the index page will be something like:
amazonPrivateIp:8080/abc/html.
How can I make godaddy direct my domain directly to this part of the instance?